# How to get the url of current html page in ionic 2

Tags: html, pdf, npm, ionic2

Is there any way to get the url of current html page to convert it to PDF by this [https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-pdf-generator] ?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current URL with `document.URL`.This will be `file:///android_asset/www/index.html#/current/router/path` on an Android device. I do not know if the pdf plugin cares about the router path but you may have to split it like that:

```
let url = document.URL.split('#')[0]
```

To get the part without the router path.